# Looking for a web-based SVN code browser (alternative for Trac); anything like Google Code?

Tags: svn, web, user-interface, source-code, trac

I'm using Trac as a web interface to an internal SVN repository. The source code browser is not the best one, so I'm looking for an alternative. Ideally, I'd like to have an interface similar to Google Code (e.g. )))[this](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/source/browse/src/Xerces/strnicmp.c), that allows navigating through code by clicking on function names etc, just like Eclipse or so.

Does anybody know about better solutions?

Comment: If you want something like Google Code you would need to code the solution yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebSVN](https://websvnphp.github.io/).

[image: WebSVN interface]

The GitHub repository is available [here](https://github.com/crazy-max/websvn).

Comment: But no releases for more than a year is A Bad Sign (at least for me)

Answer (score 0):

One option is [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/). Lightweight and nice to use.

[image: Directory view from ViewVC]

Answer (score 0):

VisualSVN Server 3.2 and newer [includes an advanced web interface for Subversion repositories](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/svn-web-interface/) built with HTML5. The interface provides a history browser, syntax highlighting, inline diffs for changed files etc.

Moreover, the web UI works out of the box; it does not require manual configuration.

[image: VisualSVN Server web interface]